# Is it possible to execute a pyinstaller bundle with fixed arguments?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Let's say we want to bundle a python program `my_app.py` which takes command-line arguments, for instance `my_app.py <input_file> --flag --optionalParameter <value>`.

Is it possible to bundle my app with *PyInstaller* such that its [bootloader](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html) will execute `my_app.py` with fixed arguments, say `my_app.py config.ini --flag --optionalParameter 42`? If it is possible, how is it done?